# SectionsPagerAdapter Android Studio template

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I am trying to use the SectionsPagerAdapter which comes with android studio. I am unable to set a fragment to it from the onCreate() of MainActivity.

mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(1)

The above statement returns a fragment and I need help in showing it in the view.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(1);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: onclick method is where I need to set the fragment to the view.

Comment: There is no Fragment in this code... Do you know how to use a FragmentTransaction class?

Comment: mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(1); This statement returns a fragment. No, I do not know FragmentTransaction class. I am new to Fragments

Comment: your question is not clear. do you want to show several fragments and switch when fab is clicked? if you wanna show fragment you should instantiate it inside your sectionspageradapter class.

Comment: if you are beginner use effective navigation from android website. It includes whole working code with sectionpageradapter. http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/EffectiveNavigation.zip?hl=vi